# Post picture to facebook page album

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a facebook page with an user as administrator. This facebook user is authenticated successfull via c# facebook sdk. Posting to the photos tab of the page works for me:

```
 FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
            fb.AppId = APPID;
            fb.AppSecret = SECRETID;
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "test1";
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\excel.jpg");
            parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                FileName = Path.GetFileName("ffdsfsa")
            }.SetValue(bytes);
            var res = fb.Post("/[photosID]/photos", parameters);  // changing to albumID does not work
```

When changing the `photosID` to an album ID posting does not work.

I did a little research and it is mentioned that I need the page access token. I try this by:

```
 FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(userAccessToken);
            fb.AppId = APPID;
            fb.AppSecret = SECRETID;
            fb.AccessToken = userAccessToken;
            Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dynamic publishedResponse = fb.Get("/me/accounts", fbParams) as JsonObject;
```

But the respsonse gives me not the accounts of the pages of the user. Do I need any specific permissions for this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need the manage_pages permission https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0 scroll to the bottom of that page

Comment: So I do need an app review for this?

Comment: I can post to photos but need addional permissions for posting photos to an album? This sound strange for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One need the extended permissions "manage_pages" and "publish_actions" to post a picture to a facebook album!