# facebook post link with a photo usung c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a new post with a photo to my feed using c# with the following code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(postInfo.access_token);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("message", postInfo.message);
        parameters.Add("link", postInfo.link);
        parameters.Add("picture", "postInfo.ImageUrl");
        parameters.Add("tags", postInfo.tags);
        try
        {
            var res = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

If I remove the picture property I can upload the post successfully, but when 
i add this property I get the following error:

```
(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

How do I suppose to do it? Am I missing some permissions?

Thanks,
Berger

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post picture to facebook page album](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758163/post-picture-to-facebook-page-album)

Comment: Hi @MethodMan, this is not a duplicate question, since I use a different facebook API here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved once I got the publish_actions permission from facebook

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [get facebook extended permission for uploading photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802197/get-facebook-extended-permission-for-uploading-photos)

> There is no photo_upload permission. But, you can upload photos using the publish_stream permission instead. And you can see the user's photos using the user_photos permission.

Comment: That’s quite an old question you are referring to here, and the answer is outdated – `publish_stream` permission doesn’t even exist any more. `publish_actions` is the permission to use now to publish anything in the name of the user.